# Standard method to integrate tools coded in multiple languages in an analysis workflow

Tags: methods

I am trying to stitch together multiple packages and tools from multiple languages (R, python, C etc.) in a single analysis workflow.

Is there any standard way to do it? Preferably (but not necessarily) in python.

Comment: I think you want [Apache Zeppelin](http://zeppelin.apache.org).

Comment: @ncasas below recommended Apache Airflow. Which one would be easy to use? Airflow or Zeppelin?

Comment: They're completely different. Take a look at them and you'll immediately recognize that one of them is not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) is an open source python package by Spotify that does exactly what you described:

> Luigi is a Python (2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5) package that helps you build complex pipelines of batch jobs. It handles dependency resolution, workflow management, visualization, handling failures, command line integration, and much more.

Its philosophy is similar to GNU Make, letting you define tasks and their dependencies.

There is also [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/) (originally from Airbnb), another python solution:

> Airflow is a platform to programmatically author, schedule and monitor workflows.
>   Use airflow to author workflows as directed acyclic graphs (DAGs) of tasks. The airflow scheduler executes your tasks on an array of workers while following the specified dependencies.

You may found a complete comparative table [here](http://bytepawn.com/luigi-airflow-pinball.html).

Comment: In Airflow you can use the KubernetesPodExecutor to start for every pipeline step a separate docker container on Kubernetes. So your're completely free to use whatever tool or programming language you can run in docker.